# What is Facebook's function __d

Tags: javascript, facebook

I'm working on a project that (hopefully) involves taking advantage of some of the javascript that's already built into Facebook. But right away I've got a roadblock in that I can't figure out what `__d` is.

If you look at the source javascript files, pretty much every command begins with `__d`

For example:

```
__d("legacy:live-timer",["LiveTimer"],function(a,b,c,d){a.LiveTimer=b('LiveTimer');},3);
```

But I can't find anywhere in any of the javascript files what `__d` actually does.  Shouldn't it have to be defined somewhere for all these other functions to take advantage of it?

**UPDATE:**

So let's say there's a site with some javascript like this...

```
function alertSomething(var) {
    if (var) alert("Here it is: "+var);
}

if (some condition) alertSomething("something");
```

Now let's say I had a Chrome Extension and I was able to inject my own Javascript into the page.  Couldn't \my Chrome Extension Javascript have something like this...

```
if (some other condition) alertSomething("something else");
```

Thus I would be taking advantage of some code that exists in the javascript already on the page?

Comment: This is the result of a JavaScript minifier.  Why is it important to you what `__d` does?  It seems like it's an internal function that you're not supposed to use.

Comment: Because if I want to take advantage of a certain line of code, I need to know what it does.  I realize it's something that's been minified, but it still has to be defined somewhere.  I thought there was no 'internal' when it came to javascript.  I should expect to still see something that says `function __d` somewhere.

Comment: What do you mean by "take advantage of"?  This function is not for you to use.  And, JavaScript *does* have private (what I meant by "internal") functions.

Comment: @StevenJenkins I found the definition of `__d` on line 20 of `1LWPxIBQ4v0.js`.  No idea if the file is named the same for you.  Look for `a.__d=function(s,t,u,v)`.

Comment: @matts This is it!  Thanks man!  If you want to submit this as an answer, I'd approve it.

Comment: @rgbflawed maybe you could change the accepted answer to the best fitting, I think it's the second one (the most voted)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As, I have inspected Facebook JavaScript SDK. I believe that it uses Dependency Injection Mechanism. Here are two URLs.

Production: http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js (obfuscated)

Development: http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all/debug.js (deobfuscated)

If you check debug.js, you can see `require, __d, __t` and many more. `__d` is more like define function from RequireJS (http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#define)

```
__d = function(/*string*/ id, /*array<string>*/ deps, factory,
      /*number?*/ _special) {/*TC*/__t([id,'string','id'],[deps,'array<string>','deps'],[_special,'number?','_special']);/*/TC*/
```

Answer (score 5):

The function `__d` is API for [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#define) used to Define a Module.

Example:

```
__d('Example', [], function a(b, c, d, e, f, g, h) {
 'use strict';
  if (c.__markCompiled) c.__markCompiled();
  f.exports = {
      a: "Hello World"
      };
 }, null);
```

Call:

```
require('Example');
```

Output:

```
  Object {a: "Hello World"}
```

Answer (score 4):

I found the definition of `__d` on line 20 of `1LWPxIBQ4v0.js`. No idea if the file is named the same for everyone. Search for "`a.__d=function(s,t,u,v)`" (`a` is the global object, i.e. `window`, effectively making `__d` a global function).  Good luck with that de-minification though...