# What's the purpose of Facebook's __d method?

Tags: javascript, facebook

I've noticed something interesting what Facebook do, and I'd like to know what they are doing and why? If you look at their source code on one of their .js files they seem to be doing a lot of this:

```
__d("AjaxRequest",["Erro...
__d("FBAjaxRequest",["AjaxRequest"...
__d("CallbackManagerController",...
```

There seems to be no variables or ordinary functions and objects in any of their JavaScript files. There are functions, but there all arguments passed to this __d method, like this:

```
__d("keyMirror",[],function(a,b,c,d,e,f){var g=function(h){var i={},j;if(!h)return h;for(j in h){if(!h.hasOwnProperty(j))continue;i[j]=j;}return i;};e.exports=g;});
```

Is this some sort of optimization for JavaScript, or is it used for easier management?

Thanks

Comment: [Relevant](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14881084/what-is-facebooks-function-d) - perhaps a dupe...

Comment: Ah didn't spot that one when I searched SO.

Comment: Yes, and there's actually an answer there (about `__d === define` in RequireJS terms) - although by some great mystery it's the other one that was accepted by the OP. Go figure.

Comment: @james - that's your mistake - don't search SO.. Search with Google - it does a much better job and the first results are always SO posts :)

Comment: Is it possible Facebook are using this ... https://github.com/amdjs/amdjs-api/wiki/AMD as it looks very similar to their __d method.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe just a wrapper that does things like dependency injection and error handling. If you can find out where `__d` is define, you'll know for sure.

It doesn't look like an optimizing (ie. a packer).

Comment: Yeah I've been looking for where __d is defined. It's there somewhere. I've tried searching the JS files for "function __d" or "__d=" and "__d =".